# helm --set to select environment

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helm3

Struggling with some helm templating...

I'm trying to pass a separate yaml file with springboot parameters to helm, and have them split by environment... then I want to pass the environment to helm using `--set env=staging`

Feels like I've tried everything but clearly I'm lacking a fundamental understanding...

My `_helpers.tpl` contains these:

```
{{- define "env" }}
{{- printf "%s" .Values.env }}
{{- end }}

{{ define "configmap.metadata" }}
  name: {{ .Values.name }}-config
{{ end }}

{{ define "configmap.properties" }}
  {{ index .Values.environment (include "env" .) "properties" | indent 4 }}
{{ end }}
```

The template for the config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  {{ include "configmap.metadata" . }}
data:
  app.properties: |-
    {{ include "configmap.properties" .}}
```

And the yaml file containing the properties looks like this:

```
environment: 
  staging:
    properties:
      spring:
        datasource:
          url: something
          username: something
          password: something
      app1:
        key: something
        secret: something
        baseUri: something
      app2:
        bootstrap_server: something
        bootstrap_port: something
        registry_schema: something

  production:
    properties:
      spring:
        etc, etc
```

And then I want to select the environment using set. I'm testing with:

```
helm template test . -f values.yaml -f properties.yaml --set env=staging
```

I think I've just tried so many things that I just can't see the wood for the trees! The error I'm seeing is:

```
Error: template: microservice/templates/configmap.yaml:7:7: executing "microservice/templates/configmap.yaml" at <include "configmap.properties" .>: error calling include: template: microservice/templates/_helpers.tpl:56:76: executing "configmap.properties" at <4>: wrong type for value; expected string; got map[string]interface {}
```

EDIT:

After tweaking, I'm still getting an error, but I'm seeing something in the configmap.. but I wonder if the error is due to the 8 spaces on the first line..

```
data:
  app.properties: |-
        app2:
      bootstrap_port: something
      bootstrap_server: something
      registry_schema: something
    app1:
      baseUri: something
      key: something
      secret: something
    spring:
      datasource:
        password: something
        url: something
        username: something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your actual error message is around the way you're using the `.Values.environment.production.properties` value.  It's a YAML map, but the `indent` function expects it to be a string.  You should be able to see some odd indentation and maybe an odd `[map spring [map datasource ...]]` string if you use the `helm template --debug` option.

When you go to render the ConfigMap, you need to make sure to do two things.  Since the data you have is structured properties, you need to use the lightly-documented `toYaml` function to convert it back to YAML.  This will begin at the first column, so you need to apply the `indent` function to it, and then you need to make sure the markup that invokes it is also at the first column (`indent` should be the only thing that supplies indentation).

```yaml
data:
  app.properties: |-
{{ include "configmap.properties" . | indent 4}}
{{/*- starts at column 1, but includes the `indent` function */}}
```

```
{{ define "configmap.properties" }}
{{- index .Values.environment (.Values.env) "properties" | toYaml }}
{{/*- starts at first column, includes `toYaml`, does not include `indent` */}}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: (It's secondary to your problem, but I also might consider having a separate values file per environment; so `helm template . -f production.yaml` and directly access `.Values.properties`, without the `environment:` block wrapper and without the `--set env=` option.)

Comment: Thanks for the information, it's starting to make more sense. I ended up suspecting it may be something to do with the yaml formatting.. with those changes I'm getting the error: `error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 9: did not find expected key` - If I use `--debug` I get `nil` in the configmap.

Comment: Ah, the issue is the first line of the yaml is indented 8.. which throws off the formatting I think...

Comment: Added EDIT above with how the CM is looking now...

Comment: `{{ include "configmap.properties" . | indent 4 | trim }}` - This resolved the issue. All is now well :) Thanks again